# How many nested options can node-red handle?

Tags: node.js, node-red

I was wondering if there is a maximum addressing depth for json formatted files in node-red.

For instance, I have a message like this

```
{ topic: 'i/devices/i/up',
payload: 
 { payload: 'oo',
   port: 2,
   counter: 54,
   metadata: 
    [ { frequency: 868.3,
        datarate: 'SF12BW125',
        codingrate: '4/5',
        gateway_timestamp: 4201744244,
        channel: 1,
        server_time: '2016-07-01T09:50:39.725658999Z',
        rssi: -63,
        lsnr: 8.2,
        rfchain: 1,
        crc: 1,
        modulation: 'LORA',
        gateway_eui: 'oo',
        altitude: 0,
        longitude: 0,
        latitude: 0 } ] },
qos: 2,
retain: false,
_msgid: '81960b41.7e69f8',
metadata: <Buffer 00> }
```

if I wan to get *metadata* option, I was addressing it within a function in node red  like

```
msg.payload.rssi = msg.payload.metadata["rssi"];
return msg;
```

However, when I attach a debug function to it, I don't get the rssi value that I want, what am I doing wrong? Cannot that field be addressed like that?

Thanks in advance

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit to the depth of a JSON object you access.

You've missed out an array index out of the selector.

What you need is:

```
msg.payload.rssi = msg.payload.metadata[0].rssi;
return msg;
```

This is because the metadata object is an array so could hold multiple instances of the metadata objects.

Also be aware that the debug tab in the Node-RED editor will truncate longer objects, if you need to see the whole object it is easiest to check the "output to console" box and the whole message will be printed to the console as well.

Comment: thanks, in case that there were more than one element of metadata, I have to create a iterator, would it be possible to know the number of elements for the iterator?

Comment: Yes, you can write a for loop and use `msg.payload.metadata.length` to know how many elements in the array